# Delete property from nested object using Lodash

Tags: lodash

Hi I have the following object:

```
{ "name": "Joe", "email": "joe.smith@test.com", "items": [ { "id": "1", "name": "Name 1" }, { "id": "2", "name": "Name 2" }...] }
```

I need to remove the name property from all the 'items', I have tried using omit but can't seem to get this working:

```
_.omit(this.user, ["items.name"]);
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The `_.omit()` method doesn't work on multiple items in this way. You can use `_.map()` with `_.omit()`:

```js
const user = { "name": "Joe", "email": "joe.smith@test.com", "items": [ { "id": "1", "name": "Name 1" }, { "id": "2", "name": "Name 2" }] }

const result = {
  ...user,
  items: _.map(user.items, user => _.omit(user, 'name'))
}

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```